# How to make function aliases?

Tags: r, alias

I am trying to create aliases for functions in R.

For example, to get the length of a vector in R:

```
length(the_vector)
#returns the length of the vector
```

I want to create an alias of the function called "len":

```
len(the_vector)
#will also return the length of the vector
```

Is there a way to do this? Key points that I want is that I want the alias to be able to take **all** arguments that could be taken by the original function, and also that the alias does not replace the original function. (i.e. in the example above, calling either `length(the_vector)` or `len(the_vector)` would provide the same result?

Comment: `len <- length`

Comment: `len <- function(x) length(x)`

Comment: Ask yourself, if you really want to do this. Your code will not work on other machines and only you will be able to read it. Is there really a good reason for wanting this?

Comment: With Russ's solution `len` will still give the same output if `length` is modified, with akrun's solution it won't (and might crash if the number of arguments of `length` changes for instance). `purr::partial` might be relevant.

Comment: @Georgery, it is portable to other machines if I include something like `source("directory/to/myfunctions.R")`. More generally, the balance against what you are saying is that since I switch between R and python, it is useful to have aliases that are similar to each other. If someone puts this as an answer I can accept it!

Comment: another reason why it's a bad idea: https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=len

Answer (score 3):

The comment from @russ-hyde provides the basis for an answer. Including:

```
len <- base::length
```

in your `.R` file creates a variable that can be used in every way that `base::length` can be used.

As long as the "alias definition" is always run as part of the source file that uses it used, this does not make it less portable. There is a case that this reduces legibility of your code, however, since collaborators may not know what to use it for.

There is also the possibility that defining `len` will cause a name conflict. But on the other hand, you might be doing this to avoid a name conflict – if, for example, you have loaded a package that defines a `length()` function you could use `len()` for the standard one. Not that in this case the `base::` prefix becomes very important to disambiguate between the multiple objects you might want to be aliasing for.

For example, `dplyr` overloads the `filter` function and is widely used. So if you need to use the original `filter` function for time series, you might want to define:

```
tsfilter <- stats::filter
```

Answer (score 0):

To not have to modify each file you're using, you can add your alias to your `.Rprofile` to be loaded automatically. I have muscle memory for using `exit` to quit a repl instead of `quit()`, so my `.Rprofile` includes

```
print.command <- function (cmd) {
  default.args <- attr(cmd, "default.args")
  if (length(default.args) == 0L) default.args <- list()
  res <- do.call(cmd, default.args, envir = parent.frame(2))
  if (attr(cmd, "print_result")) print(res)
  invisible(NULL)
}

make_command <- function(x, ..., print = TRUE) {
  class(x) <- c("command", class(x))
  attr(x, "default.args") <- list(...)
  attr(x, "print_result") <- print
  x
}

exit <- make_command(quit, print = FALSE)
```

With code modified from [here](https://davidhughjones.medium.com/r-functions-without-brackets-2052bb7ee396_)

Comment: Thanks, but the reference link is broken