# Best way to declare alias functions in R

Tags: r, alias, r-package, roxygen2

Say my package has a method `foo.A` that I do not want to export because I want the users to access it through the generic function `foo`. However, for power users that *really* want to access it, I want this method to have an exported alias `fA` (because in my real case the alias is much easier to type than the long method name). To achieve that, in addition to the code for `foo.A` I've followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48625631/1169233) and added:

```r
#' @export
fA <- foo.A
```

The problem I have with this is that the code foorprint starts getting a bit too much since I'm dealing with at least a dozen of methods in the end. So I was wondering if there's a better way to declare these aliases.

I've tried playing around with the `@export`, `@aliases` and even `@name` Roxygen tags, but couldn't quite achieve what I wanted (i.e., to hide `foo.A` and export `fooA`).

Comment: Could you expand on the problem some more?  I don't see how a single comment and assignment is too much code.  What would the ideal code look like?

Comment: "However, for power users that really want to access it" Power users know the `:::` function. Either export the function or don't, but I see no use in that alias. The length of the method names is not an issue because RStudio has auto-completion.

Comment: @user2554330, the footprint for each alias would be, in this case, 6 lines (1 for the code, 2 for the custom `@param`s, 1 for rdname to link the Rd files, 1 for `@export` and 1 white line). Not much for 1 alias, but for 12 that totals 72 lines. The final package might have at least 48 aliases for a total of almost 300 lines. I just though there would be a Roxygen tag that saves code size or at least makes things more readable.

Comment: @Roland, to expand a bit more on the issue, I'm working on some statistical distributions, so I would like to maintain the `r*` `p*` `d*` `q*` standard from the `stats` package (so the distribution abcd would have the functions `rabcd` to generate random numbers, `pabcd` pro probabilities, etc.). But since we're using S3 for method dispatching, `rabcd` is actually something like `r.abcd`, and we want users (all of them, never mind I said "power") to be able to use the former and not clutter the autocompletion with the latter.

Comment: That's just bad design. I would challenge the use of S3 classes. Stick to what is familiar to users and fully embrace the approach from package stats.